# How to install AllJoyn on Fedora 19?

Tags: fedora, alljoyn

Is there a procedure to install AllJoyn on Fedora 19?

AllJoyn site includes [the installation procedure for Debian/Ubuntu Linux only](https://allseenalliance.org/developers/develop/building/linux).

Comment: Have you installed all of the dependencies with `yum`?  What have you tried?  Is your installation failing?  If so, how?

Comment: The dependencies for Debian are not available for Fedora. When I issue `yum install build-essential libgtk2.0-dev libssl-dev xsltproc ia32-libs libxml2-dev`, I got `No package xxx available.` for all of them.

Comment: The dependencies **are** available for Fedora, they may just be called something else or packaged in a different way.  Using `yum list` and `yum search` (read the man page) you can find what you need.  For example, Fedora's `openssl-devel` package will probably provide the `libssl-dev` dependencies.  Does the `AllJoyn` build process list the missing dependencies?

Comment: @rickhg12hs, I'm sure there is a way to elaborate an installation procedure for Fedora based on the one for Debian. My question was whether someone else has gone through this process and have a ready-to-use procedure. As such, I don't have to reinvent the wheels. Based on your replies, it looks like you are not aware of the existence of such a procedure. That is enough for me. I will make one for Fedora 19.

Comment: You are correct.  You did ask for a procedure for *just* `AllJoyn`.  What I was implying is that there is a procedure to satisfy any build dependencies for Fedora given a procedure for Debian systems.  A vehicle with Debian "wheels" can easily be a vehicle with Fedora "wheels".  In addition, the `AllJoyn` build may well inform you of the specific dependencies that are required.  I wish you luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used the [build procedure for Debian](https://allseenalliance.org/developers/develop/building/linux) to make the one for F19.

#### 1. Build tools and libs

To install the equivalent of `build-essential`:

```
sudo yum groupinstall "Development Tools" "Development Libraries"
```

For the other packages, except `ia32-libs`:

```
sudo yum install gtk2-devel openssl-devel libxslt libxml2-devel
```

And for `ia32-libs`, I didn't found an adequate replacement. [It looks like this package groups many others](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/9556/how-do-i-install-32bit-libraries-on-a-64-bit-fedora/). For my case, I installed nothing. Apparently, my workstation contains already an adequate replacement (I use my workstation for development).

#### 2. Install Python v2.6/2.7 (Python v3.0 is not compatible and will cause errors)

```
sudo yum install python
```

#### 3. Install SCons v2.0

```
sudo yum install scons
```

#### 4. OpenSSL

This package has been already installed in the first step.

The remaining steps are exactly the [same as for Debian](https://allseenalliance.org/developers/develop/building/linux).